# detecting long tap on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios

I am working on an iPhone app which requires me to check if the button has been tapped & held pressed for 6 seconds & then fire an action which is playing some sort of sound.

How should I detect this 6 second tap?

On the other hand the user can also keep on tapping button for 6 seconds & then the same action should fire.

What should I do with multiple taps, how would I know that all the taps fall under the 6 second bracket?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a six second long press, use a [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) with its `minimumPressDuration` property set to 6.

Write your own [gesture recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) (say, `LongTappingGestureRecognizer`) for continuous tapping for a given period; it shouldn't be too tricky. Give it a property like `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`'s `minimumPressDuration` (say, `minimumTappingDuration`) and a property (say, `maximumLiftTime`) that determines how long a finger can be lifted off before it's not considered to be a long tapping gesture.

- When it first receives [`touchesBegan:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer), record the time.
- When it receives [`touchesEnded:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer), start an [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) (the lift timer) that sends the gesture recognizer a cancel message (e.g. `cancelRecognition`) after `maximumLiftTime`.
- When it receives `touchesBegan:withEvent:` when there's a start time, cancel the lift timer (if any).
- The `cancelRecognition` will transition to the [failed state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/econst/UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed).

There are various strategies for handling recognizing when the end of the gesture is reached, after `minimumTappingDuration`. One is to check in both the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and  `touchesEnded:withEvent:` handlers if the difference between the current time and the start time is >= `minimumTappingDuration`. The problem with this is that it will take longer than `minimumTappingDuration` to recognize the gesture if the user is tapping slowly and hir finger is down when the `minimumTappingDuration` is reached. Another approach is to start another NSTimer (the recognition timer) when the first `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is received, one that will cause transition to the [recognized state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) and that is cancelled in `cancelRecognition`. The tricky thing here is what to do if the finger is lifted when the timer fires. The best approach might be a combination of the two, ignoring the recognition timer if the finger is lifted.

There's more to the details, but that's the gist. Basically, it's a long press recognizer that lets the user lift hir finger off the screen for brief periods. You could potentially use just the tapping recognizer and skip the long press recognizer.

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is quite dated question, however answer should be pretty simple.

In your View controller ***viewDidLoad***:

```
//create long press gesture recognizer(gestureHandler will be triggered after gesture is detected)
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
//adjust time interval(floating value CFTimeInterval in seconds)
[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:6.0];
//add gesture to view you want to listen for it(note that if you want whole view to "listen" for gestures you should add gesture to self.view instead)
[self.m_pTable addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];
```

Then in your ***gestureHandler***:

```
-(void)gestureHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state)
    {//your code here

    /*uncomment this to get which exact row was long pressed
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.m_pTable];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.m_pTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];*/
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, OP describes TWO situations that should be recognized. One is a single long press (which this code detects). The other is a repeated tapping over a six-second period (which this code does not detect, I think?).  Anyway, the above code will be useful to most people, who just want to know how to set a minimum length requirement for long press.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
- (IBAction) micButtonTouchedDownAction {
    self.micButtonTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(micButtonAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.micButtonReleased = FALSE;
}

- (IBAction) micButtonTouchedUpInsideAction {
    self.micButtonReleased = TRUE;
}

- (IBAction) micButtonTouchedUpOutsideAction {
    self.micButtonReleased = TRUE;
}

- (void) micButtonAction:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self.micButtonTimer invalidate];
    self.micButtonTimer = nil;

    if(self.micButtonReleased) {
        NSLog(@"Tapped");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Touched");
    }
}
```