# One Button with Two Different Touch Events

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have been trying to implement a button with two different touch events. Let's say when user taps the button (touches for short time), it triggers actionTapped and when user touches down the button for a long time it triggers actionTouched.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284792/uibutton-touch-and-hold) may give an idea but it makes action repeat itself over and over again.

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013896/detecting-long-tap-on-iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013896/detecting-long-tap-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is my solution. scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval is the min interval that makes it touch:

```
- (IBAction) micButtonTouchedDownAction {
    self.micButtonTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(micButtonAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.micButtonReleased = FALSE;
}

- (IBAction) micButtonTouchedUpInsideAction {
    self.micButtonReleased = TRUE;
}

- (IBAction) micButtonTouchedUpOutsideAction {
    self.micButtonReleased = TRUE;
}

- (void) micButtonAction:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self.micButtonTimer invalidate];
    self.micButtonTimer = nil;

    if(self.micButtonReleased) {
        NSLog(@"Tapped");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Touched");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to setup a timer on the touchDown event, that will execute your longPress function. On the touchUp event you can cancel the timer. Rather simple really.

Comment: This is a good idea but what about distinguishing between the two events ?

Comment: The initial (short tap) code can be executed in the touchDown event, just before you setup the timer. The long press code can be executed in the timer event.

Comment: but you still get both actions executed for the same touch (in the case the timer fires off ...)

Answer (score 1):

The iOS SDK includes two gesture recognizers that are perfect for your needs:

- UITapGestureRecognizer
- UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Create your button without attaching any actions to it. Then create two gesture recognizers, one of each type, each mapped to the action you want. Then attach the gesture recognizers to the button.

Answer (score 0):

I will do the following :

1. In your touch down method : store current time (lets call it `touchDownTime`).
2. In your touch up method : calculate `time elapsed = current time - touchDownTime`

   2.1   Convert to seconds

   2.2  If time elapsed > required time do action1 (long touch), else do action2 (short touch)